# (C++) Why are additional blank lines in the text file not being counted?

Tags: c++, text-files

I have created this function to return the number of lines in a text file:

```
int numberOfLinesInFile(string dataFile){            
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("data.txt");
    int numberOfLines, data;

    while(!inputFile.eof()){
        inputFile >> data;
        numberOfLines++;
    }

    cout << "Number of lines: " << numberOfLines << endl;
    inputFile.close();
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

An interesting thing that I noticed is that the function counts the number of the non-blank lines (and an additional blank line at the end) correctly, but the additional blank lines are not being counted. For example, if this is my file:

```
234
453
657
```

then the function returns `4`, since there are four lines in the text file. However, if my file contains more than one blank line at the end:

```
234
453
657
```

the function returns `4` again.

Why is this happening? Does this have to do with the `eof` instruction?

---

EDIT:

Okay, thank you @MikeCAT for making me understand where the problem was. Based on @MikeCAT's answer, I changed the `while` loop as:

```
while(!inputFile.eof()){
        if(inputFile >> data)
            numberOfLines++;
        else{
            cout << "Error while reading line " << numberOfLines + 1 << "!" << endl;
        }
}
```

I was incrementing `numberOfLines` without making sure that the line was actually read.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case, that means changing `ifstream inputFile; inputFile.open("data.txt");` to `ifstream inputFile("data.txt");`. And you don't need to call `inputFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you are doing `numberOfLines++;` after `inputFile >> data;` without checking if the reading is successful. This is bad and lead to an extra counting.

Secondly, `inputFile >> data;` reads integer *and skip whitespace characters* before integers.

To avoid these problems, you should use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to count lines.

Also don't forget to initialize `numberOfLines`.

```
int numberOfLinesInFile(string dataFile){            
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("data.txt");
    int numberOfLines = 0;
    std::string data;

    while(std::getline(inputFile, data)){
        numberOfLines++;
    }

    cout << "Number of lines: " << numberOfLines << endl;
    inputFile.close();
    return numberOfLines;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MikeCAT. I can now see where the problem was.

Comment: You could even take this a step further and use `std::cin.ignore()` instead of `cin::getline()` so that you are not wasting memory creating `std::string` values that are not used for anything.